# Access matrix by list of matrix indices in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list of matrix indices and want to access a matrix by these indices.

Example:

```
indices = [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
mat[indices] = 0
```

This should result in `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 0, 0]]`, but unfortunately I always get "`list indices must be integers, not list`".

EDIT

As user2357112 suggests in his comment I tried the following now:

```
mat = numpy.array(mat)
indices = numpy.array(indices)
mat[indices] = 0
```

But unfortunately the whole matrix is filled with 0 now.

Comment: If you want to use NumPy syntax, you need a NumPy array, not a list of lists. Call `np.array` on your matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indices` is a regular list of tuples and can't be used to get an element of your *regular* `mat`. What you can do is iterate over your list to get your indices:

```
for x, y in indices:
    mat[x][y] = 0
```

If you want to use `numpy` methods, you need to create a numpy array. Indeed, `np.array` structure allows to use tuple to access to an element:

```
mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
for item in indices:
    mat[item] = 0
```

Comment: Wasn't me ... your solution works fine (especially since your last edit). Accepting it and voting it up.

Comment: seems reasonable to me, you could add that if he wanted to do `mat[indices] = 0` the indicies would have to be converted into `[[2,2,2],[0,1,2]]` by for example `zip(*indices)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip(*indices)` to access a numpy array by 
an indices list:

```
import numpy as np

indices = [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

>> mat[zip(*indices)]
array([7, 8, 9])
>> mat[zip(*indices)] = 0
>> mat
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: This is an alternative answer